# Как удалить пробелы в начале и конце строки?

Tags: строки, c++

Как можно удалить пробелы в начале и конце строки, используя простые функции: strcat, strchr, strcmp, strcpy, strdup, strlen, strncmp, strstr

Comment: А нафига? И строки -- это string или char* ?

Comment: Сначала напишите что-то сами, потом пишите сюда.

Comment: @alexlz, ну какoй **string**, если вопрос о strcat, strchr ... 

Естественно char \*

"А нафига?" - очевидно @Пандакун хочет trim().

Comment: @Sever, а зачем что-то искать, если за 5 минут можно самому написать ?

Comment: @Sever, если уж написал, то вряд ли с целью получить совет:

**иди погугли**, а то мы тут такими крутыми вещами занимаемся, что не до тебя.

Answer (score 6):

Для C++ и C можно использовать разные подходы. На C это

```
char *trim(char *spaced)
{
    int length = strlen(spaced);

    while (isspace(spaced[length - 1]))
        --length;
    while (*spaced && isspace(*spaced))
        ++spaced, --length;

    return strndup(spaced, length);
}
```

Идея проста: в циклах идем от начала и конца в глубь строки, пока не увидим отображаемый символ. Так получаем отбрасываемые смещения от начала и конца.

Вообще, это обычный вопрос для собеседования, есть смысл решать его самому на скорость.

Answer (score 6):

[@avp](/users/232/avp) Ну почему же?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string s("      string          "), s2;
    int i;
    char *s1 = new char[(i = s.size())+1];
    strcpy(s1, s.c_str());
    while (--i && isblank(s1[i])) s1[i] = 0;
    for(i=0; s1[i] && isblank(s1[i]); i++);
    s2 = string(s1 + i);
    delete [] s1;
    cout << '*' << s2 << '*' << endl;
}
```

Comment: @alexlz Вы `isblank'ом` еще и табы порезали.

Comment: @Котик Как я понимаю, так и надо было.

Comment: @alexlz Ну вообще у автора написано именно пробелы, а не `whitespace`, хотя, конечно, это уже глупые и никому не нужные придирки к словам :) Мне, видимо, больше нечем заняться с утра.

Answer (score 0):

Используя только эти функции (strcat, strchr, strcmp, strcpy, strdup, strlen, strncmp, strstr) - никак.

Используя strspn() (см. man 3 strspn) и strcpy() можно удалить пробелы в начале строки. Одна строчка.

Для удаления пробелов в конце потребуется strlen() и потом цикл. На мой вкус **while**.

Comment: А еще можно вначале найти два правильных индекса и применить к ним `strncpy`.

Comment: Искать индекс  все равно надо в собственном цикле. 

Вопрос же (IMHO) был о том том, как сделать trim, используя стандартные функции из libc.

Answer (score 0):

Тут два подхода

1. Изобрести велосипед
2. Использовать готовые библиотеки, например, [trim из boost::string_algo](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/string_algo/quickref.html#id3331871)

И лучше всего в С++ как можно реже, только в случае крайней необходимости, использовать голые С-строки